# Jquery DataTable order by first column in Metronic admin theme

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm using admin theme whichone created by some guy and it orders all dada by second column in my dataTables. I tried to change datatable jquery file, but nothin happened. He uses different initialization to call it..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
     App.init(); // initlayout and core plugins
     TableAdvanced.init();              
  });
```

And I don't know what to change to disable ordering or make it order by first column..
This is the theme: 
http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic_admin/table_advanced.html
Maybe someone know a answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the Sorting by the first column  you will need to use something like this

```
$("#sample_1").dataTable({
   "aaSorting" : [[0,"desc"]],
   "bDestroy":true
});
```

**Note**: Using "bDestroy" it will replace your datatable with one with the new properties, so doing this will overwrite the previous configuration of the dataTable.

I think that the best solution is to look out where the datatable is created inside that `TableAdvanced.init()`

And add the parameter aaSorting to it

```
"aaSorting" : [[0,"desc"]]
```

This could work http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Comment: that helped :) maybe have ideas how to display 20 rows instead a 10 be default?

Comment: try "iDisplayLength": 20

Answer (score 0):

In metronic admin theme there is a file "../assets/global/scripts/datatable.js" in the file find "columnDefs" you will see the below code

```
"columnDefs": [{ // define columns sorting options(by default all columns are sortable extept the first checkbox column)
                    'orderable': false,
                    'targets': [0]
                }],
```

This code is stopping first column to be sortable. And the above mentioned answer by @Eduardo Quintana is a way to making a column sortable.

Answer (score 0):

I m currently used this one. Any kind of setting this js file just adds another column like [ID] returns from your query which have no effect for sorting desc order and search option how ever other columns works fine