# Disable/Remove sortorder in Metronic Admin Theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

Please help me to disable the sortorder of Metronic Admin Theme. Or just maybe disable sortorder until user click on the sortorder icon.

I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229652/jquery-datatable-order-by-first-column-in-metronic-admin-theme), but somehow, it's not working with me too.

I already change the code from **columnDefs** (from *assets/pages/scripts/table-datatables-managed.min.js*) into:

```
columnDefs: [{
   orderable: false,
   targets: [0]
},
```

But it's not working. The icon sort always activate when I refresh page. But when I change **language** from this file, it's working. I already do the same in */assets/global/scripts/datatable.js* but it's not work too.

Please help.

Comment: Basically set `order: []` in your DataTables attributes. Disabling ordering for a column does not reset the overall default ordering, it just prevent users form ordering that particular column.

Comment: Thank you. It work. My browser cached and I need to clear cache. After chat, it worked. Thank you @davidkonrad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a working example: **But when I change language from this file, it's working.**

Provide a link to your not working code

Edit:
To disable sorting completely, use this in your init setting

```
"ordering": false,
```

While to disable for specific column(s), use this in your init setting

```
"columns": [
        { "orderable": true },
        { "orderable": true },
        { "orderable": false },
        { "orderable": false },
        { "orderable": false },
        { "orderable": true }
    ]
```

This example might help you understand sorting better

https://jsfiddle.net/g1y8eu8v/1/

Here are some reference links:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable

https://datatables.net/reference/option/ordering

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderSequence

Comment: I mean in the file there are a part for modife language. And other part is for sortorder. When I translate the language from English to Vietnamesse. The language in datable is change. But when I change the code for sortorder to "false". it's not working.

Comment: You translated the language, and the sort is disabled. Why do you need to the code to `false`.